# Crystal report version is higher

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005

In my system VS2008 was installed now I installed VS2005 and trying to open an application which was built in VS2005.
When I am building the solution in VS2005 I am getting below error:

> Error 499
>   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.5.3700.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=10.2.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304'

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like one of the projects in your solution has a reference to Crystal Reports version 10.2.3600.0 which was available with VS2005.

VS2008 has CR version 10.5.3700.0 installed on your machine, so it can't compile because the version is newer than the project expects.

You can try deleting the old reference and adding one for the 10.5.3700.0 version of CR. If that doesn't work, try installing the older version of CR on your machine.